How to get recent EclipseLink to work with recent MongoDB?
I am trying to get an existing application with EclipseLink to talk to a local MongoDB instance. I believe what I'm struggling with is version compatibility. Is there any information out there about what versions of EclipseLink can talk to which MongoDB drivers?
Alternatively, can anyone suggest a fix I haven't tried?
Eclipselink version: 4.0.2
Local MongoDB versions: 7.0.2
Tomcat version: 9.0.55
In persistence.xml:
  <persistence-unit name="MyUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>path.to.MyClass1</class>
    <class>path.to.MyClass2</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.nosql.adapters.mongo.MongoPlatform"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.nosql.connection-spec" value="org.eclipse.persistence.nosql.adapters.mongo.MongoConnectionSpec"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="SEVERE"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.nosql.property.mongo.port" value="27017"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.nosql.property.mongo.host" value="localhost"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.nosql.property.mongo.db" value="localDb"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

In Java:
@Entity
@NoSql(dataType="myTable", dataFormat=DataFormatType.MAPPED)
public class MyClass1 {
  etc...

emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyUnit");

...

            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            String q = "select m from MyClass1 m where m.value = 'value'";
            Query query = em.createQuery(q);
            result = (MyClass1) query.getSingleResult();

pom.xml:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.14</version>
        </dependency>
  

Result: blank. I've verified that db.myTable.find({value: 'value'}) works in mongosh.
Switching to a native query:
            String q = "db.runCommand({find: 'myTable', filter: {value: 'value'}})";
            Query query = em.createNativeQuery(q, MyClass1.class);

Results in the problem described here: 'no such command: '$eval'' on server localhost:27017
Going back to the JPQL query and using this Maven artifact instead:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-legacy</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
  

Results in this error:
SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-8181-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [JAXRS] in context with path [/rubixis] threw exception [jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(java.util.List, java.util.List, com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions)'] with root cause
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(java.util.List, java.util.List, com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions)'
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.nosql.adapters.mongo.MongoDatabaseConnectionFactory.getConnection(MongoDatabaseConnectionFactory.java:122)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.eis.EISConnectionSpec.connectToDataSource(EISConnectionSpec.java:155)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.nosql.adapters.mongo.MongoConnectionSpec.connectToDataSource(MongoConnectionSpec.java:181)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.eis.EISLogin.connectToDatasource(EISLogin.java:77)
...

